# An unexpected situation occurs when using django to query the q of an operation

Tags: orm

```py
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Change(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    se = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

- This is my model

```py
In [92]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=['2020-04-28','2020-04-28']),~Q(change__se__isnull=True)).count()
Out[92]: 8

In [93]: 

In [93]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=['2020-04-28','2020-04-28']),Q(change__se__isnull=False)).count()
Out[93]: 9
```

- This is my query
- I do n’t know what is the difference between the two, but the result is different
- 9 is right
- I really need help
- Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: str(Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=['2020-04-28','2020-04-28']),~Q(change__se__isnull=True)).query)
```

Out[12]: 'SELECT "app_project"."id", "app_project"."project" FROM "app_project" INNER JOIN "app_change" ON ("app_project"."id" = "app_change"."project_id") WHERE (django_datetime_cast_date("app_change"."date", \'UTC\', \'UTC\') BETWEEN 2020-04-28 AND 2020-04-28 AND NOT (
"app_project"."id" IN (SELECT U0."id" FROM "app_project" U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_change" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."project_id") WHERE (U1."se" IS NULL AND U0."id" = "app_project"."id"))))'

In [13]: str(Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=['2020-04-28','2020-04-28']),Q(change__se__isnull=False)).query)
Out[13]: 'SELECT "app_project"."id", "app_project"."project" FROM "app_project" INNER JOIN "app_change" ON ("app_project"."id" = "app_change"."project_id") WHERE (django_datetime_cast_date("app_change"."date", \'UTC\', \'UTC\') BETWEEN 2020-04-28 AND 2020-04-28 AND "app_
change"."se" IS NOT NULL)'